# Creating new network interfaces from a list in ansible task

Tags: networking, ansible, ifconfig

I looked over [this](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/list_of_network_modules.html) list and i didn't find any answer on how to create a new network interface like you usually do with `ifconfig'. What i want to achieve is create an interface for every string item in a variable list, but before that i want to delete all interfaces excluding the one that ansible-playbook is using for deploying a play. Does any of you have an idea how to approach such task ?

Comment: why a downvote ? pointout problems with question and i will try to fix it

Answer (score 1):

The NMCLI module is probably your best bet among the official modules.

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/nmcli_module.html

You're going to want to do something like:

- Enumerate all interfaces into list (using either Ansible variables or parsing ifconfig output)
- Identify the one Ansible is connected over
- Exclude Ansible interface from list (using Jinja2 filters probably)
- Use NMCLI to remove all interfaces in filtered list.
- Use NMCLI to add all interfaces in separate list.

Comment: I would question the rationale of doing what you propose.  Are you sure you want to remove interfaces every time you run the playbook?  It seems counter-productive to Ansible's philosophy of idempotency.

Comment: i'm running a proxy server with changing pool of ip addresses so i want occasionally to be able to change all the interfaces i use with ansible assistance.